# 2D Unity: expand UI element based on text to the bottom

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I've got a game object (InfoBox) with a..

- Vertical Layout Group (Padding 20 on all sides, Control Child Size Height active)
- an image
- a Content Size Fitter (Vertical Fit set to Preferred Size, Horizontal Unconstrained)

Inside this InfoBox is a Text-Element and every time I update the text, I want the InfoBox to expand or collapse, but to the bottom only. Right now my InfoBox always expands or collapses to both top and bottom, but I don't want that to happen. How can I achieve that? I added some screenshots to better visualise this.

These are my settings for the InfoBox:

[image: InfoBox Settings]

And these are my settings for the text:

[image: Text Settings]

And this is what happens when I use for example less text, the box collapses from bottom and top, but I want it to stay fixed at the top (on the same line as the green box next to it) and only collapse on the bottom:

[image: How it should not be]

Any help is really appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You main issues looks like you are using a `ContentSizeFitter` also on the parent object. So it depends how this parent object is aligned with its according parent.

This sentence sounds strange I know but what you did is basically shifting up the alignment responsibility to the parent.

=> Make your UI element aligned to the top and grow downwards.

All you need to do for this is either set

- Anchors Min y -> `1`
- Anchors Max y -> `1`
- Pivot y -> `1`

or simply go to the `RectTransform` Inspector, open the alignment tool and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click on the top alignment:

[image]

---

For the second instead of using the `ContentSizeFitter` I prefer to have my own script that only does what it should and nothing more.

You can get the [`preferredHeight`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text-preferredHeight.html) which is exactly the value you are looking for.

The following script simply always applies the preferred height to the text rect. Using [`[ExecuteAlways]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteAlways.html) this also works in edit mode. Simply attach it on the same `GameObject` as the `UI.Text` component

```c#
[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform))]
public class TextHeightFitter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private RectTransform _rectTransform;
    [SerializeField] private Text _text;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!_text) _text = GetComponent<Text>();
        if (!_rectTransform) _rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        var desiredHeight = _text.preferredHeight;
        var size = _rectTransform.sizeDelta;
        size.y = desiredHeight;
        _rectTransform.sizeDelta = size;
    }
}
```

[image]